# Vue 3: how to sequentially add an element one after another?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tableau-api

My problem is the following:

I need to render a bunch of Tableau graphs on a page.
I am currently calling them in `tableau-graphs` component as follows:

**TableauGraphs Component**

```html
<template>
...
  <tableau-graph
    v-if="urls.length > 0"
    v-for="(chartUrl, index) in urls"
    :src="getVizUrl(chartUrl, ticketList[index])"
  />
...
</template>
```

When I do this, all the charts are called immediately one after another, and tableau decides the order in which they are loaded. This behaviour is undesired because there might be many graphs and tableau can decide to load a graph much further down on the screen before the first one.

I want to try to do the following:

1. make `tableau-graph` component `emit` a `ready` event once its loaded.
2. the parent `tableau-graphs` listen to that event and load the next chart in `urls`.
3. repeat 1-2 until there are no more charts to load.

I have gotten the child component to emit a custom event and listen to it. However, I have not been able to programmatically add a new component in the template. I have tried using `h` function but I am unsure how to mix it with a regular `template` syntax.

So, my questions are:

1. How do I programmatically add an existing Vue component to another in `script setup`?
2. Is this a desirable way to go about solving this issue, or is there more elegant way to solve this problem? (For example, using Async Components and/or `Suspense`)

Comment: You could indeed use lazy loaded components + intersectionObserver to anticipate their visibility to have some kind of pagination loading. Loading it for free (if the user have not scrolled yet) is not the most efficient because it may still make your page unresponsive (in terms of reactivity).

Comment: @kissu by lazy loaded component, do you mean [Async Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#loading-and-error-states)?

Comment: Yes, as detailed here: https://vuejs.org/guide/best-practices/performance.html#code-splitting

Comment: As I understand, you just need to push a new `chartUrl` into the `urls` array whenever the parent listens to a `ready` event @cSharp